# Where do I put my start up script for mysql? 

Tags: server, mysql, upstart, init.d

I have created a second instance of MySQL on the server for replication, if I start the process manually it works but need it to start at bootup.

I used to just do a bash script in the init.d folder but apparently that no longer works on 11.10

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I even copied the mysql service, changed it and tried that but it refused to work.

P.S It is the server edition so only Shell access.

Comment: I know `upstart` isn't really well-documented, but I found the [cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) yesterday -- it looks helpful.

Comment: I'm still putting all my scripts in /etc/init.d and I've never had a problem with them running automatically on boot. Was something supposed to have changed?

Answer (score 1):

Converted comment to answer

I'm still putting all my scripts in `/etc/init.d` and I've never had a problem with them running automatically on boot. Was something supposed to have changed? – ovangle Nov 17 '11 at 16:06

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd want a local replica of the mysql database, but it should be simple enough. You probably just need to create an upstart job file that runs your init.d script after mysql is started, and stops it when mysql is about to stop.

```
start on started mysql
stop on stopping mysql

pre-start exec /etc/init.d/yourscript start

post-stop exec /etc/init.d/yourscript stop
```

Comment: @SpamapSFrom Neo - "its a remote MySQL database not the local one but thanks anyways"